# AutoSave not working in PowerPoint for pptm file

Tags: powerpoint, autosave

When I try to turn on AutoSave in PowerPoint (Microsoft 365 version) for a .pptm file, I get this message:
[image: Error message]

I assume this is because I'm using the pptm format, but I can't find any doc that says this is unsupported. In fact, [this doc says it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/how-autosave-impacts-addins-and-macros).

> You can also take steps as a developer to mitigate these problems so
> that your add-ins and macros work smoothly, even if AutoSave is
> enabled.

If AutoSave of a pptm file is unsupported, when did that happen and where is it documented?
Otherwise, any ideas on how I can get AutoSave working? I was going to use Office Add-ins instead of VBA until I found how severely limited the API is.

Comment: From the Help text that displays after that message: 
*AutoSave does not support this file format. AutoSave only supports the modern, native, Office file formats such as .DOCX, .XLSX, or .PPTX; and it doesn't currently support .PPTM or .DOCM files. You can still manually save your file by going to File > Save or pressing CTRL + S (Windows) or Command + S (Mac).*

Comment: AutoSave only applies to files stored in the cloud, and Office in the cloud doesn't support macros/PPTM. You can certainly save your PPTM files to a local drive, but you'll have to develop your own AutoSave by training your fingers to press CTRL+S every so often.